# C# Get Memory Physical Address Ranges

Tags: c#, windows

I'm writing a little system information tool in C#.

Registry key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\RESOURCEMAP\System Resources\Physical Memory` contains the following values for physical memory ranges:

[RegistryImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbbFH.png)

I am wondering where I can get these values without parsing the registry using C#?

I looked up all values in WMI with https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2 but couldn't find any info.